# How to remove a row from a child table if it is removed from a parent one?

Tags: sqlite

Here is a simple shema:

```
sqlite> .schema recordtypes
CREATE TABLE recordtypes (record_id text primary key);
sqlite> .schema headers
CREATE TABLE headers (header_id text primary key);
sqlite> .schema record_to_headers
CREATE TABLE record_to_headers (id INTEGER, recordid TEXT, headerid TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(recordid) REFERENCES recordtypes(record_id), FOREIGN KEY(headerid) REFERENCES headers(header_id));
```

Then I insert values into `recordtypes` and then in `record_to_headers`:

```
sqlite> insert into recordtypes values("test");
sqlite> insert into record_to_headers values (1, "test", "yeah");
```

Then I remove the "test" from `recordtypes` table expecting it is removed from `record_to_headers` table also but this never happens:

```
sqlite> delete from recordtypes where record_id = "test";
sqlite> select * from recordtypes;
sqlite> select * from record_to_headers;
1|test|yeah
```

I need behavior if I remove the value from `recordtypes` table it is also removed from `record_to_header` table. Please advice how to do so. Thanks a lot.

Comment: create an on delete trigger. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that much experience with SQLLite, but from the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) I can see, that SQLLite supports foreign key cascading. That would delete the child row when parent row is deleted:

```
FOREIGN KEY(headerid) REFERENCES headers(header_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

You should consult the documentation to see whether you need to configure something beforehand in SQLLite.